# Django - How can objects be ordered by specific order?

Tags: python, django

I need to order the objects that .order_by() returns, so that all the objects that their "status" field **is 5** will be in the end. How it can be done?

Comment: What are the other possible values in the status field?

Comment: You can do two queries -- one filtered for status not equal 5, then same query for status = 5

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple `order_by` fields in your queryset. So if 5 is the maximum value for the `status` field you can use:

```
qs.order_by(..., 'status')
```

Otherwise you should use queryset's [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra):

```
select={'custom_sort_field': 'status=5'}
qs.extra(select=select).order_by(other_order_by_field, 'custom_sort_field')
```

This way you create a custom sort field which is `True` when `status = 5` and `False` otherwise. So when you sort by this field, the `True` values go to the end as `True > False`.

Comment: I was under the impression you can't order by a calculated field.  No?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this at database level but you can fetch all the records then sort in Python:

```
object_list = sorted(MyModel.objects.all(), key=lambda obj: 999 if obj.status == 5 else obj.status)
```

This will sort objects by `status` but objects with `status==5` will be assumed as status being equal to 999, thus moved to the end. This obviously assumes that you don't have any object with `status >= 999`

Comment: For some reason it orders it rendomly. here is the code: `calls_raw = (q1 | q2).order_by('-status', 'date') `   
    `calls = sorted(calls_raw, key=lambda obj: 999 if obj.status == 4 else obj.status) ` . any ideas why?

Comment: Is your status field numeric? Can you post the relevant parts from your model code? Besides, it re-sorts everything so your `order_by` is irrelevant in this case.